# How to group consecutive values in reguarly time spaced series?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, pandas-groupby

I need to separately analyse the records between holes contained in a regularly spaced time series.

As example in the follwing time series regularly spaced every 6 seconds there is a gap between 00:24 and 00:54:

```
2018-01-01 00:00:00     4.2
2018-01-01 00:00:06     4.1
2018-01-01 00:00:12     4.3
2018-01-01 00:00:18     3.4
2018-01-01 00:00:24     4.7
2018-01-01 00:00:54     3.3
2018-01-01 00:01:00     8.2
```

I need to separately analyse the two following groups:

Group one:

```
2018-01-01 00:00:00     4.2
2018-01-01 00:00:06     4.1
2018-01-01 00:00:12     4.3
2018-01-01 00:00:18     3.4
2018-01-01 00:00:24     4.7
```

Group two:

```
2018-01-01 00:00:54     3.3
2018-01-01 00:01:00     8.2
```

Multiple holes are contained in a huge dataset and the analysis requires to compare consecutive groups.

Here it follows some code to reproduce the example:

```py
data_index = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-01 00:00:00', '2018-01-01 00:00:
06','2018-01-01 00:00:12','2018-01-01 00:00:18', '2018-01-01 00:00:24', '2018-01-01 00:00:54', '2018-01-01 00:01:00'])
data = [4.2, 4.1,4.3,3.4, 4.7, 3.3, 8.2]
df = pd.DataFrame(data_index, columns=['date'])
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df.set_index('datetime')
df.drop(['date'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df['data'] = data
```

Comment: so whats the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create separate dataframe using [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

```
groups=( df.index.to_series().diff()>=pd.Timedelta(seconds=6) ).cumsum()+1
for i , group in df.groupby(groups):
    print(group)

                     data
datetime                 
2018-01-01 00:00:00   4.2
2018-01-01 00:00:06   4.1
2018-01-01 00:00:18   3.4
2018-01-01 00:00:24   4.7
                     data
datetime                 
2018-01-01 00:00:54   3.3
2018-01-01 00:01:00   8.2
```

---

**Detail**

```
print(groups)

datetime
2018-01-01 00:00:00    1
2018-01-01 00:00:06    1
2018-01-01 00:00:18    1
2018-01-01 00:00:24    1
2018-01-01 00:00:54    2
2018-01-01 00:01:00    2
Name: datetime, dtype: int64
```

---

to analyze the different dataframes you could save them in a dictionary:

```
dfs={i:group for i,group in df.groupby(groups)}
print(dfs[1])
                     data
datetime                 
2018-01-01 00:00:00   4.2
2018-01-01 00:00:06   4.1
2018-01-01 00:00:18   3.4
2018-01-01 00:00:24   4.7

print(dfs[2])
                     data
datetime                 
2018-01-01 00:00:54   3.3
2018-01-01 00:01:00   8.2
```

Comment: Really thank you for your reply but I made a small misleading mistake in my example. I missed a row and I just added it because I am looking to any hole greater than the sampling period. Your reply is still perfect, however, I invite you to edit the timedelta comparison  to > 6 secs.

Comment: You are welcome ! Do you mean : `groups=( df.index.to_series().diff()>=pd.Timedelta(seconds=6) ).cumsum()+1`?

Comment: yes but `groups=( df.index.to_series().diff()>pd.Timedelta(seconds=6) ).cumsum()+1` otherwise everysteps is a new group.